# Loading html data from page source into webview

Tags: java, android, html, webview

I'm trying to load a page in my webview by copying the html source (right click page, select 'View page source') and pasting it into my HTML file that I have in my android's 'assets' folder.

The problem I encounter is that when I use `webview.loadUrl(myUrl);` it loads the page but it's mostly black and white, I dont see any colors.. usually only the links show (the links are clickable but don't work, they just give me a Webpage not available error) and thats about it.

How would I fix this behavior?

my code looks like this

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.myWebview);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){   
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }
        });


        String myUrl = "file:///android_asset/Assets.html";
        webView.loadUrl(myUrl);


    }
```

the Assets.html file contains all the HTML code obviously.

Comment: Does the web page reference any external css files in the header or are all the styles declared in Assets.html?

Comment: Everything is declared in Assets.html

Comment: For example, the HTML source is from www.google.com

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

It was the encoding.

Unfortunately I am not sure what encoding to use but this is how I solved it.

When I copied the source from a different web page, and tried to run my app, an error showed up, it said that certain characters contained in the HTML source needed a different encoding to run, as soon as I selected "Change encoding" within the message that popped up, and ran the app, the website loaded fine.